# Get content from another site

Tags: javascript

I saw here similar questions but I didn't find any answer about Javascript.

I'm building a web site (lets call it 'A'), and I want to get content from another web site ('B') that requires a user-name and password.
I want a function at my site that get the content from a certain page at B. I'm always login manually to site B at my computer so I don't need the function to do the login (so I link it directly to the correct page of the info at B).
A and B are not in the same domain. Is there a way in Javascript to get content from B?

Answer (score 5):

You need a cross-doman AJAX call (normally prevented by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). jQuery has a handy helper function for this that will return JSON data called [`$.getJson()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON('http://otherdomain/ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  if (undefined != data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

This exploits a technique known as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which writes Javascript directly into the document to make the request (instead of using the `XMLHttpRequest` object), bypassing the same origin policy.

Comment: Well, just wanted to know if there is a way to do that at pure Javascript, but guess not, so I'll start reading about AJAX. Thanks!

Comment: jQuery is a library written in Javascript, so is "pure" in-as-much as a library can be :)

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do is use YQL (Yahoo Query Language)
It's like an api for api's. I get whatever html I want using selectors and process that.
For example, I can grab all the images from [this wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_National_Parks_by_state) using a query like
`SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_National_Parks_by_state" AND xpath="//img"` and then processing the returned XML/JSON

you can test queries [HERE](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)

and see an example of grabbing and processing the images [in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3wX6/)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to get content from external `B` page using pure `javascript`, but you can try to use php `curl` or `file_get_contents`

Comment: That what I thought but I hoped there is a way.. Thanks !